# ¿Cómo quitar a un tipo de dato number el exponente y mostrar todos los deciamles en Angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, pipe

Tengo un servicio en Java que consulta a una base de datos y regresa una lista, la cual contiene valores tipo Double muy grandes, y cuando los muestro en mi frontend (Angular) los muestra con un exponente y no los muestra completos como en la base de datos

Asi se muestran en la base

```javascript
0.00000000130499999999998494601667672321700842198
```

y asi lo muestra en mi frontend, como que lo redondea y no lo muestra completo

```javascript
0.0000000013049999999999848
```

Hice lo siguiente en mi html, el campo  **valores.NoOpciones** es un tipo de dato que lo declare asi
**fnNoOpciones!: any;** y se llena cuando se manda a llamar al servicio java

```html
<td>{{valores.NoOpciones | number: '0.0-47'}}</td>
```

pero por que como que lo redondea y no lo muestra tal cual en la bd?
qué debo de agregar o modificar para mostrar el numero completo?

mi servicio en java es el siguiente:

```html
@Service
    public class ConsultarValoresServiceImpl implements ConsultarValoresService{
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresRepository consultarValoresRepository 
        
        @Override
        public List<ValoresDTO> consultarValores(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) {
        try {
            Integer ini = fechaInicio;
            Integer fin = fechaFin;
            return consultarValoresRepository.consultarValoresBd(ini, fin);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

cambie el atributo de Double a String unicamente en mi clase modelo

```html
@Column(name="NOVALORES")
private String NoValores;
```

y en mi front solo lo mostre asi, sin el pipe

```html
<td>{{valores.NoValores}}</td>
```

Comment: Si sólo es para presentarlo en la vista (que no hacer operaciones con el valor), podrías convertir el número flotante (`double`) en su representación de cadena (`string`) en Java y así enviarlo a la vista. Saludos

Comment: ya cambie mi tipo de dato  String en mi clase Java, pero lo muestra igual como lo mencione ya, como redondeado y no completo

Comment: Pero estas usando el pipe `number` todavia?

Comment: @Andres si, por que si lo quito me lo muestra con el exponente

Comment: Pero si lo muestra con el exponente entonces no es un string.
Podrías mostrar el servicio en Java que parsea el `double` a `String`?

Comment: @AndresGardiol lo que hice fue cambiar mi tipo de dato de Double a String en  mi clase Modelo en Java, lo  agrego a la pregunta, y en PANTALLA lo muestra asi 1.73999999999999356985251903913431458401E-09

Comment: No importa si es string o numérico, javascript al ser de tipado dinámico tratara de redondear los números grandes

Comment: @Charls entonces no hay manera de mostrarlo copleto?